# Steamworks: Проверка сборки не удалась

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, steam

Сделал 2D игру, на С# и Monogame. 
Отправил её в steam на проверку.

Пришел ответ:

> The build review has failed because the game doesn't launch, and we weren't able to find a solution to get the game working. It's possible there's an issue with the game files, but there might also be one or more missing dependencies. Please test and resolve this launch error issue before submitting for review again.

Но у меня игра запускается и ещё я попросил многих родственников запустить игру у себя на компах и у них все запускается.
Все работает как в windows 7 так и windows 10.

В чём может быть проблема ? 
Кто сталкивался с подобным и как вам удалось это решить ?

Я не могу скинуть сюда весь проект, но скину скрин файлов сборки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вас же явно написали, проверьте все зависимости. Для проверки поставьте например Windows 7 на виртуальную машину, и попробуйте запустить сборку там. И зачем вы показываете файлы отладочной Debug сборки? Соберите Release и опубликуйте через Build - Publish. К тому же Debug сборка намного медленнее работает, чем Release с установленной галкой Optimize code.

Comment: Я поставил release - игра запускается - как и раньше.
Я могу отправить в steam теперь уже release сборку, а не debug, но есть ли смысл ?.
У них моя игра не запустилась только из за debug сборки, но почему тогда у меня и у моих знакомых, которым я скидывал игру, запустилась ?. Как это вообще работает ?

Comment: Поставьте чистую Windows, и попробуйте запустить там.